# How will SPFx on SharePoint-Online detect the language

Tags: spfx-webparts

Regional Settings in related SharePoint-Site?
  -- What about alternate activated languages?
  -- What about preferred language setting in user profile?

So, who will win when opening a page with a localized SPFx-WebPart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SharePoint Framework WebPart use what SharePoint gives it through `_spPageContextInfo.currentUICultureName`. So it will pick language as expected.

More information here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/localize-web-parts